# dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue() UI weirdness

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

This is for MacOS not iOS.

If your running code on a GCD queue

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //do UI stuff
});
```

is pretty much the way to do UI stuff on the main thread/queue which seems to work well for iOS.
MacOS seems to be a different story.
Try this for a simple example

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // So my app is doing some background stuff
        // and I need a file from the user so

        // code blah blah code

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSOpenPanel *op = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

            [op runModal];
        });

        // resume code blah blah code
    });
}
```

when the NSOpenPanel opens all kinds of weirdness is going on. The scroll views scroll very erratically if at all and the directories don't list properly. I'm just using the NSOpenPanel here as an example, this also happens with any view that contains a scroll view (so I've tested so far).
Is this a bug?
Are others seeing this or is it just me and is there another preferred way of doing this?

Comment: `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` is absolutely not "the way" to do UI stuff -- it's actually a huge potential problem; Details here: http://bit.ly/1qCrZTp You want to use `dispatch_async` when dispatching to the main thread from a global background queue. If you need continuation behavior (i.e. for the remainder of your background task to wait until after the UI update completes) you should find another way. A `dispatch_async` back to the background thread from the end of your main thread block is the most obvious way, but `dispatch_group_notify` is another, etc).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are blocking the main thread as the main_queue is a serial dispatch queue. The main thread cannot run as it's blocked in the `runModal` method.

Following the discussion [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/324612-nsopenpanel-runmodal-on-dispatch.html), the solution is to use `beginWithCompletionHandler:` instead, which I have verified to work:

```
//[op runModal];
[op beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    NSLog(@"Done: %lu", (unsigned long)result);
}];
```